# Login Screen appears with back key pressed and on app restart

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my application user need to Login to access the application. My problem is when ever user press back key from main activity, user is send back to Login screen.

I know i can override ht OnBackPressed() but this doesn't solve my problem. If i override OnBackPressed() and sent user to home screeen, user will be shown back login screen when user opens the app again. Even though user has been shown with login screen, user is on background logged in. So in order to go to main activity, user need to log in again.

I tried Finish() but mono droid shows error.

I have attached my login activity code herewith.
Somebody might get me out of this problem.

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RestSharp;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Requests;
using TheNorthStar.Api.Results;
using NorthStar.Driver.Application;
using Android.Preferences;
using Object = Java.Lang.Object;


namespace NorthStar.Driver
{
    public class DriverLogonAsync : AsyncTask

    {
        private ProgressDialog processDialog;
        private Context m_context;
        private DriverLogon m_driver;

        private bool _resterror;

        public DriverLogonAsync( Context context, DriverLogon driver )
        {
            m_context = context;
            m_driver = driver;

            _resterror = false;
        }

        /*
         * throws
         * should separate out logic and use MyMessagebox..
         */
        private void SetComfirmAlertBox(string carNum, DriverLogonResult result)
        {
            var api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(m_context));
            string resultOfCarDetail; CarDetails res;
            try
            {
                resultOfCarDetail = api.ComfirmLogginOn(m_driver);
            }
            catch
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_conflogon1", "confirm logging on failed");
                throw;
            }
            try
            {
                res = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CarDetails>(resultOfCarDetail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_conflogon2", "deserialize confirm logging on failed\n" + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }

            if (res.carExists != true)
            {
                MyMessageBox.SetAlertBox("Opps!!!!!!!!", "This Car Number Was Wrong!!!!", "OK", m_context);
            }
            else
            {
                string carType = res.carType;
                string seatNum = res.numOfSeats.ToString();
               // MainActivity act = new MainActivity( result.driverId );
                var mact = new Intent(m_context,typeof(MainActivity) );
                mact.PutExtra( "driverID",  result.driverId.ToString() );
                MyMessageBox.SetAlertBox("Comfirm!", "Your car is a: " + carType + " with " + seatNum + " seats??", "Yes", "No", mact,m_context);


            }
        }

        /*private void ChangeDriverStatues()
        {

        }*/

        protected override void OnPreExecute()
        {
            base.OnPreExecute();
            processDialog = ProgressDialog.Show( m_context, "Driver Loging On...", "Please Wait...", true, true);
        }

        protected override Object DoInBackground(params Object[] @params)
        {
            var api = new ConnectToSever(Helper.GetServer(m_context));

            string res = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                res = api.DriverLogingOn(m_driver);
            }
            catch
            {
                _resterror = true;
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_dlogon1", "driver logon failed");
                return -1;
            }
            return res;
        }

        protected override void OnPostExecute(Object result)
        {
            base.OnPostExecute(result);
            //hide and kill the progress dialog
            processDialog.Hide();
            processDialog.Cancel();

            if (_resterror == true)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_dlogon2", "logon connection has failed, noop");
                return;
            }

            DriverLogonResult resDriverDetail;
            try
            {
                resDriverDetail = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DriverLogonResult>(result.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_dlogon3", "logon deser has failed, noop\n" + ex.Message);
                return;
            }

            if (resDriverDetail.logonSuccess)
            {
                this.SetComfirmAlertBox( m_driver.carNum, resDriverDetail );  
            }
            else
            {
                MyMessageBox.SetAlertBox("Wrong!", "Wrong username or password!!!", "OK!",m_context);
            }
        }
    }

    [Activity(Label = "MyDriver-Driver", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Android.Util.Log.Info("EXC_logstart", "**************** starting driver module ****************");

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            EditText eTextUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.UserNameBox);
            EditText eTextPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PasswordBox);
            EditText eTextCarNum = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.CarNumBox);
            Button viewPrefsBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnViewPrefs);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            button.Click += delegate 
            {
                if (eTextCarNum.Text != "" && eTextPassword.Text != "" && eTextUsername.Text != "")
                {
                    DriverLogon driver = new DriverLogon();
                    driver.userName = eTextUsername.Text;
                    driver.password = eTextPassword.Text;
                    driver.carNum = eTextCarNum.Text;
                    DriverLogonAsync asyDriver = new DriverLogonAsync(this, driver);
                    asyDriver.Execute();
                }
            };

            viewPrefsBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(PreferencesActivity));
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your login activity is probably your first activity. Don't do that, have your main activity check if the user has already entered the login credentials and if not - fire the login activity from it.

That way, when you're done with the login and back to the main activity, back will get you to home screen. And when you run the application, you'll get the main activity.

Comment: Thanks for you information. I am very new to this platform. Some code example will help me lot. Also I tried shared preferences but I really don't know how to use it to save user credentials.

Comment: Sorry, I've only played with Monodroid for a few minutes, I can't point you to code samples.

Comment: Can you give me example on Android, i can make it for monodroid myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply saving the login information via `SharedPreferences`, and checking of the login info is already present in shared preferences on the login activity? You could then simply push the user to the main page if the data is already present.

Answer (score 0):

Login Screen: If user is logged in (ex: you could use SharedPreferences for saving state) then move to the main activity and then call finish() on login screen to finish that activity. It should work.

As you said it crashes on finish(). You should look at the error log why it's crashing on calling finish and fix that.